# WCF - One OperationContract sees Web.config, another doesn't

Tags: wcf, web-config

I have a WCF service with two methods, Ping and PutAddress.  Ping works fine, but PutAddress was failing to initialize NHibernate correctly.  Narrowing down the issue, I realized that the relevant settings from Web.config were not being read by PutAddress.

Strangely, Ping *does* have access to the settings from Web.config.  I removed all of the NHibernate code and boiled it down to just trying to read the settings.  Ping is able to read the settings (returns non-null, values in *result* are correct) while PutAddress' *result* is null.

Again, NHibernate is now completely out of the picture.  Both methods simply try to read the relevant settings from Web.config.  Ping succeeds while PutAddress fails.

Any thoughts?

Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{

    [OperationContract]
    string Ping();

    [OperationContract]
    Address PutAddress(Address address);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public string Ping()
    {
        NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSchema.HibernateConfiguration result = 
           (NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSchema.HibernateConfiguration)
         System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("hibernate-configuration");
        if (result == null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); // Does NOT break, "Pong" returned 
        }

        return "Pong";
    }

    public Address PutAddress(Address address)
    {
        NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSchema.HibernateConfiguration result =
           (NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSchema.HibernateConfiguration)  
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("hibernate-configuration");
        if (result == null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); // Breaks, result is null
        }

        return address; // Return version potentially modified with DB-assigned ID
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Here is the (sanitized) Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- NHibernate Section -->
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler,NHibernate"/>
    <!-- Log4Net Section -->
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <!-- NHibernate Configuration -->
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="dialect">
        NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect
      </property>
      <property name="connection.provider">
        NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
      </property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">
        NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver
      </property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">
        Server=localhost;Database=DB;User ID=USER;Password=PASS
      </property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <mapping assembly="MyService"/>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
  <!-- Log4Net Configuration -->
  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender, log4net">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout, log4net">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
      <param name="File" value="log.txt"/>
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
      <param name="DatePattern" value="yyyy.MM.dd"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
        <conversionPattern value="%d %p %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <priority value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="NHibernate" additivity="false">
      <level value="WARN"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    </logger>
  </log4net>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sanitized version of your web.config?

Comment: Are you able to step through the WCF code in a debugger?  I suspect that this could be caused by a serialization issue and not by lack of access to web.config.  Otherwise, could you use `Msgbox("X")` in your code to ascertain the flow of execution?

Comment: Yes I can step through.  Changed to only use primitive types and still get the same result.

Comment: Found the problem... see my answer below.  Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem - one call was from a Unit Test that I hand-coded, which uses MyServiceClient that was generated by Visual Studio when I added a Service Reference.  The other call was from a unit test that was created by the Visual Studio (2010) Unit Test wizard, which just instantiated MyService as an object.  The VS-generated unit test was running in-process as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I had an odd problem myself.  I could not return "DataTable" objects from a WCF operation.  I wonder if there could be a problem with returning an "Address" object from a WCF operation as well.

I don't know the complete answer to your question, but I would suggest the following

In your code for `PutAddress`, try replacing `Address PutAddress(Address address);` with `string PutAddress(Address address);` and replace `return address;` with `return "Pong"`

By doing so, you will ascertain the flow of execution through your code.  Make sure that you are actually breaking and returning null as opposed to returning a null value of `address`.

If the new code returns null, then you are in fact having trouble reading from the file.  I suspect that it will actually return "Pong", indicating that your code is returning Address, which somehow contains null because of WCF weirdness.

Comment: I changed PutAddress to accept and return a string.  Also changed both to just return "NO CONFIG - Ping" / "NO CONFIG - PutAddress" instead of breaking into the debugger.  Ping still succeeds and PutAddress still fails.